# Swift UITableView numberOfRows Error When Added or Removing Rows in Section

Tags: swift, uitableview, header, row, sections

I've been experiencing a very annoying issue this week. I have a UITableView that generates a number of sections (with section headers), each section always having 3 rows.

I've implemented a hiding/showing section functionality when a section header is tapped, where all the rows in that section are either deleted or inserted accordingly. Everything works perfectly fine and as expected... 70% of the time. I find that once I start dragging around the UITableView a bit while tapping on headers and just being all around random, it crashes unexpectedly with the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (3 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Below is my relevant code:

```
    @IBOutlet var pastWinnersTableView: UITableView!

    var previousWeeks : [PreviousWeekData] = []
    var hiddenSections = Set<Int>()
    var firstTimeLoading = true ///This is needed to allow all the past week cells to start off as minimized

    //This function runs in response to a section header being tapped in the table view.
    @objc func expandCollapseSection(section: UIButton){

        pastWinnersTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {

            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

            for row in 0..<3 {

                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row, section: section.tag))
            }

                return indexPaths
            }

        //If the section was previously hidden...
        if hiddenSections.contains(section.tag) {
                hiddenSections.remove(section.tag)
                pastWinnersTableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsForSection(), with: .fade)


        //If the section was previously showing...
        } else {
            hiddenSections.insert(section.tag)
            pastWinnersTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsForSection(), with: .fade)
        }
    }


    //MARK: - REQUIRED METHODS
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if firstTimeLoading == true || self.hiddenSections.contains(section) { return 0 }

            else { return 3 }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        let numberOfPreviousWeeks = previousWeeks.count

        if numberOfPreviousWeeks > 0 {return numberOfPreviousWeeks} else {return 0}
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let weekNumber = previousWeeks[section].weekNumber

        let headerButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            headerButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
            headerButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            headerButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            headerButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
            headerButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Mouse Memoirs", size: 30)
            headerButton.backgroundColor = task.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "5B3F22")
            headerButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            headerButton.titleLabel?.shadowColor = .black
            headerButton.titleLabel?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            headerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandCollapseSection), for: .touchUpInside)

            headerButton.tag = section
            hiddenSections.insert(section)
            headerButton.setTitle("Week \(String(weekNumber))", for: .normal)

        return headerButton
    }

    //This footer is essentially just a small blank space.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pastWinnersWeekFooterCell") as! PastWinnersWeekFooterCell

        return footer
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat { return 45 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat { return 5 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return UITableView.automaticDimension }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return 44 }



    //PreviousWeekData[(weekNumber, firstPlacePlayers[(username, score)], secondPlacePlayers[(username, score)], thirdPlacePlayers[(username, score)]), (weekNumber,...)]
    //This defines the tableViewCell that holds all 3 placement sections with all the winners for a given week 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let weekSection = indexPath.section
        let weekData = previousWeeks[weekSection]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pastWinnersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PastWinnersTableViewCell

        cell.thisWeeksData = weekData
        cell.winnersCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.frame = tableView.bounds;
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.winnersCollectionView.reloadData()
        cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.winnersCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;

        return cell
    }
```

Any ideas why it would be crashing on me with that error only sometimes? (ie. once I start dragging it around a bit and THEN tapping on headers? Tapping on my section headers is always a 3 in, 3 out deal so I'm not sure why it's getting confused.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of deleting/inserting rows, why don't you just vary the height instead? Ex: When you want to hide a row, set its height to 0.

Comment: The error is basically saying that you are trying to insert 3 rows in a section that already contains those 3 rows. So that's a total of 6 rows instead of the expected 3 rows after the update.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is. You are appending a value to your hiddenSections Set inside of the viewForHeaderIn section function. That function can be called multiple times while you are scrolling up and down and there could be a mismatch between the cells you are displaying and the content of your hiddenSections Set. I think you are making this more complicated than it should be to be honest. Try initializing that Set in viewDidLoad for example.

Comment: Those are 2 great suggestions and I will try implementing them tomorrow evening once I’m back at it! I guess I figured viewForHeaderInFunction was only called once for each header the first time they are created, and I wanted to append them to that Set so that each section is initialized as hidden (closed), but I didn’t account for the fact that it’s called much more than that as sections are dequeued and re-added when scrolling. So it’s possible! I’ll try moving that to viewDidLoad(). If that doesn’t work, I’ll try the 0 height thing and will report back. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: No problem. If you are still stuck, let me know.

Comment: Wow you're incredible! I couldn't figure that out for several days and then you took only a few minutes to find the issue :P It 100% WAS the line `hiddenSections.insert(section)` in my `viewForHeaderInSection` method. It was likely crashing because of the reason you suggested. Instead of moving it to viewDidLoad() though, I moved it to the end of my function that retrieves the data I need from the server so that I know how many sections I need to create, then I simply did a for loop to iterate over that Int to initialize my Set<> with the list of values. Thanks so much!!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I was able to help.